# Problemas Envio de Datos Axios y React Native

Tags: react-native, axios, apk

recientemente desarrolle una aplicación con react native con envios post con axios, un  sistema con un login de inicio, que envia los datos de user y pass a un servidor y este responde success o fail, el problemas surge de la siguiente manera, cuando el dispositivo esta conectado directamente al la pc para las pruebas este envia correctamente los datos y recibe la respuesta "success", cuando ya despliego esta app a un archivo APK este envia los datos y recibe la respuesta "fail", es decir que solo cuando esta conectado funciona correctamente, lo confuso es que la aplicacion APK envia y recibe información correctamente en dispositivos de android 5.0 y 6.0 para abajo pero para superiores tiene ese fallo. seria posible que alguien se halla encontrado con ese error.

Comment: Hola, Marcelo. Bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Te invito a realizar un [tour] para que conocas cómo funciona el sitio y ganes tu primera mesa.

Comment: estoy teniendo mismos problemas, pudieron solucionarlo ??

Answer (score 0):

debe ser por que ahora Android requiere URLs seguras, tu "endpoint" debe estar en "https", esto se actualizo en las ultimas versiones de Android.

Checate también esto en AndroidManifest.xml, agregar "usesCleartextTraffic"

```
<manifest 
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28"> 
    ... 
    </application>
</manifest>
```